# Jackson DeSerializer for Class<? extends Foo>

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I want to have a Serializer and Deserializer for Class Literals. It should be mapped from / to JSON Strings. And it should also work with generic classes.

I tried writing a custom Deserializer, but it handles all Classes, not just the ones I want:

```
public class MyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Class<? extends Foo>> {
    public Class<? extends Foo> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String token = jp.getText();
        switch(token) {
            case "FOO": return Foo.class;
            case "BAR": return Bar.class;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Jackson will call this Deserializer for EVERY `Class<?>`. But I just want it to get called for `Class<? extends Foo>`.

Btw: I want to register this as a global Deserializer. I **don't** want to use `@JsonDeserialize` everywhere.

How can I get this working properly?

Thanks in advance.

### EDIT: Some more code

POJO:

```
public class MyPOJO {
    public Class<? extends Foo> fooType;
}
```

JSON:

```
{
    "fooType": "FOO"
}
```

ObjectMapper usage:

```
MyPOJO pojo = new MyPOJO();
pojo.fooType = Foo.class;

ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
String json = om.writeValueAsString(pojo);
```

Comment: Could you please add code for Json POJO and using of `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: added some code

Comment: If you don't want to use @ JsonDeserialize, could you use @ JsonIgnore only where needed? (ie transients&not Serializable)

Comment: @Shine: Nope. I should be possible to have `JsonDeserializer<Class<? extends Foo>>` and `JsonDeserializer<Class<? extends AnotherClass>>`. And Both must apply to different classes. At the moment when using `JsonDeserializer<Class<? extends Foo>>` it will run for **every** kind of class, even for `Class<Object>`.

Comment: If it is not of type `Class<? extends Foo>` but any other class what do you expect it does ?

Comment: @Nicolas Filotto: Then it should use Jackson's default behavior. My problem is pretty similar to deserializing a custom `List`, **but** for a custom `List` I could simply do `MyList extends ArrayList<Foo>` and then write a (de)serializer for `MyList`. Here Jackson would look for a deserializer for `MyList` and if there is none, it would use the default `List` deserializer. But of course it's not possible to extend `Class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you try to achieve seems to be impossible due to [*Type Erasure*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), indeed at runtime your class `MyDeserializer` is seen as a `JsonDeserializer<Class>` and your field `fooType` is simply of type `Class` not of type `Class<? extends Foo>` that is actually why your deserializer is called for every `Class<?>`.

In your case the best solution would be to annotate your fields of type  `Class<? extends Foo>` with `@JsonDeserialize(using = MyDeserializer.class)` in order to indicate at runtime the deserializer to use but as you don't want to do it, as workaround, assuming that in given class when you have fields of type `Class` they will all use the same deserializer (custom or default), you could simply modify your class `MyDeserializer` to check first the current bean class to know whether we should use the custom deserializer or the default one.

You would register it for example as next:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyModule")
    .addDeserializer(Class.class, new MyDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

The code of your deserializer would then be:

```
public class MyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Class<?>>  {

    // The default deserializer for a property of type Class
    private final FromStringDeserializer.Std defaultDeserializer;

    public MyDeserializer() {
        // Set the default deserializer
        this.defaultDeserializer = FromStringDeserializer.findDeserializer(Class.class);
    }

    public Class<?> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // Check whether we should used the custom or default deserializer
        // based on the bean class
        if (accept(jp.getCurrentValue().getClass())) {
            // The custom deserializer
            String token = jp.getText();
            switch(token) {
                case "FOO": return Foo.class;
                case "BAR": return Bar.class;
            }
            return null;
        }
        // Call the default deserializer
        return (Class<?>) defaultDeserializer.deserialize(jp, ctxt);
    }

    // Returns true if this bean class has fields of type Class that must
    // be deserialized with the custom deserializer, false otherwise
    public boolean accept(Class<?> beanClass) {
        // Implement your logic here
        // You could for example have all the bean classes in a Set and 
        // check that the provided class is in the Set 
    }
}
```